# JsonMappingException no single-String constructor/factory method Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to parse JSON data being sent from UI in my Controller using Spring build Jackson support and this is my code

```
final Map<String, CartDataHelper> entriesToUpdateMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(entriesToUpdate, new TypeReference<Map<String, CartDataHelper>>()
```

my JSON string is

```
{"0":"{\"categoryCode\":\"shoes\",\"productCode\":\"300050253\",\"initialQty\":\"3\",\"leftoverQty\":\"0\",\"newQty\":\"3\"}",
"1":"{\"categoryCode\":\"shoes\",\"productCode\":\"300050254\",\"initialQty\":\"3\",\"leftoverQty\":\"0\",\"newQty\":\"3\"}"}
```

i checked the JSON format using some online services and it seems valid, while tryin gto parse JSON data i am getting following exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class controllers.util.CartDataHelper] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method
```

my `CartDataHelper` class contains simple properties for for `productCode`, `categoryCode` etc with a no argument constructor

Comment: That JSON data looks like its been double-escaped. So while it may be valid, I don't think it represents what you think it does. It represents an object with two properties ("0", and "1") each with  a value that looks like a JSON encoded object represented as a string.

Comment: @Ramon:is there way to change the structure to meet this?

Comment: It depends on the code that produced it, I guess.

Comment: how you creating your JSON data? can you show that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As comments mentioned, your JSON contains `Map<String,String>` and NOT `Map<String,CartDataHelper>`: values are JSON Strings, not JSON Objects.

Ideally you would not try writing out objects as JSON Strings; and if so, things would work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on the client side the json is sent as a string instead as an object. That way on the server side you are receiveing a string and not a CartDataHelper as you pretend.

Try sending `JSON.parse(stringCartDataHelper)`. It worked for me with the same issue.